# Convert column names From Upper Case to lower case using the for loop

Tags: r

I want convert the column names in lowercase using the for loop

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(1, 2), b = c(2, 3)), .Names = c("a", "b"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

If i use R base functions easily can convert

```
colnames(df) <- toupper(colnames(df))
```

But when i use following R code unable to done

```
for( i in colnames(df)){
    colnames(df[i]) = toupper(i)
     return()
 }
```

Please tell me where i did mistake ,Thankyou.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in loop?

Comment: This is simply not something you should do with a for loop in R

Comment: `janitor::clean_names()` (it's in CRAN and here https://github.com/sfirke/janitor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df[i]` is a different object to `df`. While `colnames<-` has side-effects to change an object in place, you are not giving it `df` to change. You need to rewrite in a way that `df` can be modified, for example:

```
for( i in colnames(df)){
    colnames(df)[which(colnames(df)==i)] = toupper(i)
 }

df
  A B
1 1 2
2 2 3
```

Also, you should not return from a for loop at the top level, which causes an error.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this with a `for` loop over the number of column names:

```
for (i in 1:length(colnames(df))) {
    colnames(df)[i] = toupper(colnames(df)[i])
    # return()     ... you don't need this
}
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

He was faster than me. You can also skip `lenght(colnames(df))`:

```
for( i in 1:ncol(df)){
   colnames(df)[i] <- toupper(colnames(df)[i])
}
```